# How do I handle the Firebase Simple Login for facebook callback in phonegap?

Tags: facebook, cordova, firebase, firebase-security

Building first *firebase* app using *phonegap* and *angularjs*.  It authenticates fine in Chrome and I get back the fb user id.

My problem is when I build it with *phonegap 2.9* and login with *facebook* I get nothing but a white screen after login.

My limited understanding is that I'm probably not handling the callback correctly.

In my console logs I see:

```
Finished load of: https://auth.firebase.com/auth/facebook/callback/?firebase=mementomori
&internalRedirect=false&code=AQDLp_n5_JCnC4yc1OXcXhd2Xfty_UHy_2bmOpR
-JIbyeEZQfh9LCf02deQkXbtXQknxYpTf_XHGFiy4DB1S4Do6fILTmFZ2_z
-S_N872VhwtlWkkOam4I9iMKoqa8PF43jIIdfvTpg8CwPZMs3YrVwqwuJRKzkovBL6nWI8vtdSa
_CFnEhHanXHoaJ3mH7d2vmbhmNGusBkfRdqXnd3LEC1rUyY7hrEr4pfN3BCRAzzgY_
YTot0CUoqRImLPAI76qc18KWaCytZ0ueaMnH7zavkvNExpVSiKlPQBdLUQmFmZQa
FQc6gNWm3dfZTAJw9hLg#_=_
```

Can anyone offer any information on how I should handle this callback properly?

***Solution***
I got around my issue by logging in with the native phonegap fb plugin and then passing the auth tocken to firebase for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Firebase Simple Login with Phonegap, there are a few prerequisites:

- You've included `phonegap.js` or `cordova.js` in your application.
- Enabled the `InAppBrowser` plugin in your application.

With both of the above configured, Firebase Simple Login will behave equivalently in PhoneGap as in on desktop / web, where the callback you passed to the Simple Login constructor is invoked with login error or user object. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response Rob.  I had included both js files and enabled the InAppBrowser already.  It works fine in chrome. but on mobile in a compiled phonegap project I have the white screen of death.

I got around my issue by logging in with the native phonegap fb plugin and then passing the auth tocken to firebase for authentication.

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution to use the built-in angularfire login directly rather than with the access token?